# Material Design: EditText's highlight color becomes half transparent

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

In Android 5.0 device, you can see the highlight color overlaps the normal color.

[image]

In Android 4.4.4(the normal case),

[image]

My EditText:

```
<EditText android:layout_width="320dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/account"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

v21 Style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
</style>
```

I don't know why this happened.

<strike>The code works great at another app.</strike>

<strike>But I could not find any difference between two apps.</strike>

Does anyone know about this ?

Thanks!

---

[UPDATE]

Sorry, also happen to the other projects with the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

I report the issue and got reply from Google.

> The EditText drawables were updated in 5.1 (which is what 4.4 and below are using).
>
> Since the visual change is small it's not worth updating these for 5.0.x.
>
> Thanks for the report though.

Answer (score 0):

add this for your styles.xml(v19) and styles(v22) :

@color/colorHighlight

You can do like this :

in the styles.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and for styles.xml(v19) :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorHighlight</item>
```

and for styles.xml(v22) :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTransitionBackgroundFadeDuration">5000</item>
</style>
```